# `gcloud preview app deploy` gives MaxRetrialsException in version 105.0.0

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

When I run `gcloud preview app deploy` with Cloud SDK version 105.0.0, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (MaxRetrialsException): last_result=(None, (<class 'googlecloudsdk.calliope.exceptions.BadFileException'>, BadFileException('[.../source-context.json] not found or not accessible',), <traceback object at 0x7f7bb4ab07e8>)), last_retrial=3, time_passed_ms=1,time_to_wait=0
```

Answer (score 9):

This is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=727), and is fixed in the 106.0.0 Cloud SDK release. **Please update to that release.**

If you cannot, work around by running:

```
gcloud config set app/use_gsutil true
```

This particular issue happens when using `gcloud` to deploy to a 'standard' (as opposed to a 'managed VM' or 'flexible') App Engine app that has a `.git` directory.